# $location.path is not redirecting to page in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

Here is the code.In URL it is redirecting to `#!/dashboard` but it is not displaying anything.

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "Login.html"
    }).when("/dashboard", {
        tepmlateUrl: "Dasu.html"
    });
});

app.controller("LoginCtrl", function ($rootScope, $location, $scope) {
    $scope.submit = function() 
    {
        debugger;
        if($scope.userid == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin')
         {
            $rootScope.LoggedIn = true;

            $location.path('/dashboard');

         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is that... client side authentication...?

Comment: Yes,it is client side authentication.

Comment: Not related to the question, but I assume this is only for testing out things?

Comment: Yes.It is related to testing.

Comment: I see for the dashboard route config you have 'tepmlateUrl', should be templateUrl. Not sure if it's just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typeo in your $routeProvider config

```
.when("/dashboard", {
        tepmlateUrl: "Dasu.html"
});
```

Should be

```
.when("/dashboard", {
        templateUrl: "Dasu.html"
});
```